# Can't install pip packages on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

When I try to install any pip package I get the same thing. Here is what I get ↓↓

```
PS C:\Users\amin_\Desktop\Basel\programming> pip install xarray


ERROR: Exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\amin_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-

packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 167, in exc_logging_wrapper

    status = run_func(*args)

  File "C:\Users\amin_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-

packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 205, in wrapper

    return func(self, options, args)

  File "C:\Users\amin_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-

packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 287, in run

    session = self.get_default_session(options)

  File "C:\Users\amin_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-

packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 75, in get_default_session

    self._session = self.enter_context(self._build_session(options))

  File "C:\Users\amin_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-

packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 89, in _build_session

    session = PipSession(

  File "C:\Users\amin_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-

packages\pip\_internal\network\session.py", line 282, in __init__

    self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()

  File "C:\Users\amin_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-

packages\pip\_internal\network\session.py", line 157, in user_agent

    setuptools_dist = get_default_environment().get_distribution("setuptools")

  File "C:\Users\amin_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-

packages\pip\_internal\metadata\__init__.py", line 75, in get_default_environment

    return select_backend().Environment.default()

  File "C:\Users\amin_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-

packages\pip\_internal\metadata\__init__.py", line 63, in select_backend

    from . import pkg_resources

  File "C:\Users\amin_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-

packages\pip\_internal\metadata\pkg_resources.py", line 8, in <module>

    from pip._vendor import pkg_resources

  File "C:\Users\amin_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-

packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3252, in <module>

    def _initialize_master_working_set():

  File "C:\Users\amin_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-

packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3235, in _call_aside

    f(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\amin_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-

packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3277, in _initialize_master_working_set

    tuple(

  File "C:\Users\amin_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-

packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3278, in <genexpr>

    dist.activate(replace=False)

  File "C:\Users\amin_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-

packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2785, in activate

    declare_namespace(pkg)

  File "C:\Users\amin_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-

packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2284, in declare_namespace

    _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)

  File "C:\Users\amin_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-

packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2217, in _handle_ns

    loader.load_module(packageName)

  File "C:\Users\amin_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pygoogle\google.py", line 

113

    print """PyGoogle %(__version__)s

    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?

WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
```

Comment: What is your python version?

Comment: There is some confusion with python 2 and 3. Try using pip3 instead of pip.

Comment: Seems you are trying to run legacy python 2 script on python 3

Comment: @AsadullahNaeem everything points to a `Python310` folder, so it is safe to assume that it is python 3.10

Comment: I'm using python 3.10.4

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be in a third-party package that you installed at some point:

```
C:\Users\amin_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pygoogle\google.py
```

Here you get an issue because it contains the line `print """PyGoogle %(__version__)s`, which is old python2 syntax. This is not really suprising, because [pygoolge was last released in 2006](https://pypi.org/project/pygoogle/). I would suggest you run

```
pip uninstall pygoole
```

Comment: now I tried to uninstall pygoogle and I got the same thing

Comment: Try removing the folder `C:\Users\amin_\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pygoogle`. To be save, start by moving it, e.g. to your desktop. Then try a `pip install` command again